# How can we create first time user : customer group in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I wish to use coupons for first time user, for this want to create one custom customer group which will be only registered not buyer to website. How to achieve this ?

Comment: how you define an user as `first time user` and what is means by  `only registered not buyer to website.`

Comment: @AmitBera it means there should not be any order placed by the particular user  we can say OrderCount =0 .